# Is there a good way to minify both CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, gruntjs

I tried both htmlmin and cssmin and neither could do both:

I have CSS/HTM modules that I need minified.  The CSS is written inline using

```
<style>
```

I swear I have used a grunt tool to do this before but both these tools did not work:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
```

I use one for html and one for CSS but I need a tool that can do both as I don't want to de-couple my HTML/CSS modules.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an online tool that will minify any markup you give it (this includes CSS and JS in your markup): http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Comment: but I need it in grunt

Comment: Oh, here's a site that might suit your needs: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin